# Python error (invalid syntax) in string like " "$xyz" "

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I am trying to send mail from a remote computer(Linux) over SSH using paramiko using the `mail` command. The exact command is

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command("echo "$email_body">email.txt")`
```

I get a invalid syntax error at the `$`. What's wrong here?

Comment: See the code highlighting of your command. What you think is an inner quote is actually the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the double quote `"` as your string delimiter so you can't have it also inside your string because that will end the string in the wrong place. You can either escape the inner quotes like this `\"` or use single quotes inside your string.

So this:

```
"echo \"$email_body\">email.txt"
```

Or this:

```
"echo '$email_body'>email.txt"
```

Comment: These are shell commands to be executed on the remote computer, so i can't make any changes to them. Using """  """ (tripple ") works.